# Codeblocks - Code Does Not Recompile After Changing Header File

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm using code blocks to work on an STL header library. I am currently using this header file in a main.cpp file. I am able to build the project just fine. However, when I make changes to the header file and then rebuild, it says that no changes have been made and thus won't rebuild. Instead, I have to make a change to the main.cpp and then it will let me rebuild.

It's as if code-blocks doesn't look to see if changes were made in the library when deciding whether or not it needs to rebuild.

I've searched all over trying to figure this out and haven't had any luck. I'm assuming there is an option in code-blocks somewhere, but I can't find it. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Add the header files to your project.  It will put them in a 'Headers' section  , based on extension, from which point they are available for searching, and change-detection

Comment: BTW you can alawys click on 'Rebuild' to force rebuild

Comment: @M.M So this is another question I have. The way I have been including the header file is by adding it to the 'search directories' option in the compiler. How do I go about just adding it directly to my project? I had tried this earlier, but the header file is 'grayed' out and will insist that it's not in the project. Any ideas?

Comment: go "Add Files" from the "Project" menu. They greyed-out indicates that the files are not being compiled directly (which is correct)

Comment: @M.M So I retried this and the file stills shows up as 'grey'. I go to the project tab, and then chose 'add files' and then navigate to my header file. This header file is located with the projects 'include' directory, yet it is still gray....

EDIT: Okay, I reread this and understood that it should indeed be grayed out. However, why am I get an error message from the compiler stating that it kind find my header?

Comment: Error message from the compiler is nothing to do with adding files to your project.  For filenames to used in `#include` you must specify their paths via `-I` commandline options , which can be configured by Project > Build Options > Search directories > Compiler. (be aware to choose the global option on the left-hand pane there, and the right Policy)