# Header files will not compile

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, codeblocks, header-files

I am working on a large C++ project in the Code::Blocks IDE. I regularly am making changes to the header files, like adding new function and variables to classes. For some reason, recompiling the project does not pick up on these changes.

Other forums suggested that IDEs like Code::Blocks do not recompile header files. Why? How can I change this? I need the header files to regularly recompile every time I make a change.

I have tried both the "build" and "rebuild" commands, but the compiler still does not recognize that I have made changes to the header file.

How do I recompile the project in Code::Blocks so that changes to my header file are recognized?

Comment: Only `cpp` (source) files are compiled.  If header files are not `#include` into at least one `cpp` file then their contents will not be processed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35907199/560648

Comment: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=9920.0

Comment: Are the header files you edit included in the project? They may not even be.

Comment: Have you checked that the precompiled header option has not been activated for those files?
See http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Precompiled_headers